# saving row as a template using WPBakery Page Builder is not working

Tags: wordpress-theming, wpbakery

I am working on theme development and using "WPBakery Page Builder" for creating pages. I am getting below mentioned error while save row as template by opening edit row settings and click on gear icon. It gives me following error::

> TypeError: $ is undefined
>
> plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/backend.min.js:10:82695

I am saving row as a template like this::

[image]

I have deactivated all the plugins except js composer and tried to save row as template but still it returns me same error.

I thought there might be an issue with mytheme so I have activated Twenty Nineteen default theme and trying to save row as a template, but I am getting save error.

Any solution? Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved in latest version of js composer plugin: 6.1

Comment: In some cases, the problem is fixed in bakery version 6.5. In bakery changelog file says "Fix: Template saving works properly"